# Нормально ли хранить тесты сайта в таком варианте в бд, или есть более правильные решения

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, mysqli, архитектура, структуры-данных

Например сам тест представляет из себя заголовки в которых содержится несколько подзаголовков, в которых уже содержатся вопросы, поэтому хранение в простой таблице не представляется возможным. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас я просто перевожу весь тест в json и впихиваю в ячейку бд, подскажите пожалуйста насколько это правильно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще как то режет глаз создание отдельной ячейки для каждого теста, хотя тесты и разные, но похожие элементы присутствуют. Стоит ли из-за этого беспокоится если сервис рассчитан не более чем на 3 теста

Comment: Если вам не нужно по этим полям что-то искать и отдельно их менять, то и норм. Кстати, некоторые БД умеют работать с `json`, искать прямо в полях `json`-а и т.д.

Comment: Почему нельзя создать нормальные таблицы и структуру БД? Так-то конечно можно, но искать и вообще работать с этим запаришься. Лучше сразу сделать нормально.